# Is it possible to change ejabber jId using XMPP Framework iOS

Tags: ios, xmpp, ejabberd, xmppframework, mongoose-im

Is there any option to change my jId (ejabberd ID) using XMPP Framework iOS?
suppose currently my jID is 12345@localhost. I want to change it to 6789@localhost.
Its like change phone number feature in WhatsApp.

Can anybody help me please. which class or method to change it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no.

A JID is the unique identifier of an entity in an XMPP system. Changing a JID would imply changing all the persistent data (own roster, buddies' rosters, temporarily stored offline messages, past chat history, group chat room membership, ...). I don't know of an XMPP server having this functionality built-in and as far as I can tell there's no XMPP extension defining such a feature.